# Updating h:inputHidden on tab change

Tags: jsf, primefaces, hidden-field

I have a Primefaces tab view with two tabs and a `inputHidden` element with some string in it. On the first tab there is a `commandButton` that changes the value of an `inputHidden` element. I'd like to use that changed value in a `useText` JS function, but I get an old value of a hidden field.

After updating my hidden field, it IS updated but an output text on a second tab is not updated and I don't understand, why.

```
<h:form id="formMain">
      ...
    <p:tabView onTabChange="useText(#{bean.text});">
        <p:tab title="tab1">
            <p:commandButton value="Change" action="#{bean.doBtnChangeText}" update=":formMain:hidArray @(.textTest)" />
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="tab2" >
<h:outputText styleClass="textTest" value="#{bean.text}" />
        </p:tab>
    </p:tabView>
      ...
<h:inputHidden id="hidText" value="#{bean.text}" immediate="true" />

</h:form>
```

EDIT: I added some output text on a second tab to check for updated value. I updated both, hidden field and output text, on a command button. Hidden field is updated but output text is not.

Comment: Did you try using `update` on your command button? Please read http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/basic.xhtml

Comment: I'm aware of how `update` works. I updated my hidden field on command button and it is updated, but when I click on a second tab, old value appears (added some output text for testing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding `id` attribute to `h:outputText` element.

```
<h:outputText id="outText" styleClass="textTest" value="#{bean.text}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jasper said, you can try `update` on your command button, or try to update directly from bean, on your `doBtnChangeText()`, just call `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("form:hidText")`.

Comment: My mistake, I have updated a hidden field, but I didn't post that part of code, sorry. Updated my question. The problem is that an output text on a second tab is not updated even though I updated that element beside hidden field.